# Вместо реакт компонента отображается emodji

Tags: html, react-native

Всем привет! Проблема заключается в том, что на айфоне в горизонтальном положении отображается emodji, вместо svg path. На остальных устройствах все ок

Так должно быть
[image: так должно быть],

Так отображается
[image: так отображается]

Не выдает ошибку при просмотре страницы через код обработчика, только с самого устройства, поэтому не могу понять откуда копать

Вставляю компонент

```
<span>
<Play width={23} />
</span>
```

Сам path

```
<svg width="26" height="31" viewBox="0 0 26 31" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M25.1 16.8655L2.8 29.9655C2.6 30.1655 2.1 30.1655 1.9 30.1655C1.7 30.1655 1.2 30.0655 1 29.9655C0.4 29.5655 0.1 29.0655 0.1 28.3655V2.36549H0C0 1.66549 0.4 1.06549 0.9 0.765486C1.4 0.565486 2.2 0.365486 2.8 0.765486L25.1 13.7655C25.7 14.1655 26 14.6655 26 15.3655C26 16.0655 25.6 16.6655 25.1 16.8655Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

Буду рада любым идеям, спасибо

Comment: посмотри какой элемент находится в DOM в этот момент

Comment: в дом все как нужно, на компе вообще этого бага нет, в коде разработчика он тоже не отображается

Comment: ты проверяла dev tools на телефоне?

Comment: нет, только узнала, что такое есть, спасибо! дальше сама)